# How different UITableView sections store values in different NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I'm retrieving values of "style" and "category" from a Web Service. Both of them are showing separately in `UITableView`. 
Multiple cell selection option is also available. I've made to `NSMutableArray` and I want when user selects a value from styles section it's values goes into one array and similarly the other section values goes in other array. And when he deselect the values it should be removed from array. The code below is not showing any value that if it is stored or not. All it prints is `(null)`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
        if (indexPath.section==0)
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            selected[row] = NO;
            NSLog(@"indexpath zero of un-select");
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            selected[row] = NO;
            NSLog(@"indexpath else of un-select");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (indexPath.section==0)
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            selected[row] = YES;
            [self.styleSelect objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
            NSLog(@"indexpath zero of select, %@",self.styleSelect[indexPath.row]); //this prints (null)

        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            selected[row] = YES;
            [self.categorySelect objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"indexpath else of select, %@",self.categorySelect[indexPath.row]); //this prints (null)
        }
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You question is not clear. Please make it clear.

Comment: question is why is it printing null or should I say why it is not storing the values in the array.

Comment: Please share how you declared and initialized styleSelect & categorySelect.

Comment: I've initialized the array in `.m` file after `@interface` and before `@implementation` the code I wrote for that is `@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *styleSelect; @property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *categorySelect;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        if (indexPath.section==0)
        {
            [styleArray removeObject:indexPath];
        }
        else
        {
            [categoryArray removeObject:indexPath];
        }
    }
    else
    {
         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        if (indexPath.section==0)
        {
            [styleArray addObject:indexPath];
        }
        else
        {
            [categoryArray addObject:indexPath];
        }
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it prints "null" it simply means that you didn't initialize arrays,or you have NSNull objects on such indexes . Also the calls before NSLog,i.e. accessor calls are redundant. I.e. there should be addObject instead of objectAtIndex, plus arrays should be created.

```
        if (!self.styleSelect) 
             self.styleSelect = [NSMutableArray array];
        [self.styleSelect addObject:@(indexPath.row)];   

        NSLog(@"indexpath zero of select, %@",self.styleSelect[indexPath.row]);
```

Comment: I've initialized the array `@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *styleSelect;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *categorySelect;`